# exit from parent function according to ajax success callback return value

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
//this function will upload file through ajax
add: function (e, data) {

        //before upload file check server has that file already uploaded
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType:'json',
                    url:"../admin/cgi/file_check.php",
                    async:false,
                    data:{  
                             filename : upload_filename,
                             docname : upload_docname,
                             userid : upload_userid,
                        },
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        //check file alreay exists
                        if(data['doc_name'] == 'invalid')
                        {
                            // if file alreay exists want to stop upload process
                            //exit from main funtion
                        }

                    },
                    error:function(request,errorType,errorMessage) 
                    {
                        alert ('error - '+errorType+'with message - '+errorMessage);
                    }
            });

            //file uploading code

            }
```

`add: function (e, data) {}`  - main function upload file through ajax
before upload check server has that file already uploaded through ajax request
if file alreay exists ajax success call back return the value `data['doc_name'] = 'invalid'`

if file alredy exists `if(data['doc_name'] == 'invalid')` i want to stop uploading proccess (want to exit from main uploading function)

Comment: `return false;` not working???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this: If your ajax returns invalid then display error message otherwise upload file.

```
success:function(data)
 {
       //check file alreay exists
       if(data['doc_name'] != 'invalid')
       {
             //file uploading code
       }
       else
       {
            // Display your error message.
       }
 },
```

Comment: Please, add some description before your code sample